# Change of variable to transform non-autonomous linear ODE to autonomous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, change-of-variable

Given the equation

$$
\begin{cases}
(t^2+1)x'(t) - y(t) = 0 \\
x(t) + (t^2+1)y'(t) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Find an appropiate change of variables to transform the system into an autonomous one. In a previous part of the excercise we find that the non-null solutions are non-periodic, if that helps at all.

I've tried several different changes of variable, including polar coordinates, $(u,v) = (tx,ty), (t^2x,t^2y), (x/t,y/t)$ but none of them seem to work. I suspect that the change itself has to necessarily depend on $t$ because otherwise I can't imagine how the $t$'s would fade, but other than that I'm clueless.

Any hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
(t^2+1)x'(t) - y(t) = 0 \\
x(t) + (t^2+1)y'(t) = 0
\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{y}{t^2+1} \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{x}{t^2+1}
\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad
\frac{dy}{dx} =-\frac{x}{y}
$$
$$ydy+xdx=0\quad\implies\quad d(y^2+x^2)=0$$
$$y^2+x^2=C=\text{constant}$$
The real solutions are the circles with center $(0,0)$.

If you want $x(t)$ solve $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\pm\sqrt{C-x^2}}{t^2+1}$ which is separable. An similary for $y(t)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{cases}
(t^2+1)x'(t) - y(t) = 0 \\
x(t) + (t^2+1)y'(t) = 0
\end{cases}$$
Try to substitute $u=\arctan t$
$$x'(t)=\dfrac {dx}{dt}=\dfrac {dx}{du}\dfrac {du}{dt}=\dfrac 1{t^2+1}\dfrac {dx}{du}$$

Then the system becomes:
$$\begin{cases}
x'(\tan u) - y(\tan u) = 0 \\
x(\tan u) + y'(\tan u) = 0
\end{cases}$$
Here $x'(u) $ means $\dfrac {dx}{du}$. You can also rewrite the system as:
$$\pmatrix {x \\ y}'=\pmatrix {0 & 1 \\ -1  & 0}\pmatrix {x \\y}$$
$$X'=AX$$

Comment: I get that $(\tan^{-1}(t))' = t^2+1$ but what does $x'(u)$ mean in the new system? Is that the derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$ or $u$? If it is with respect to $u$, how is it equivalent to the first system if the original one had $x$ evaluated in t and this one has $x$ evaluated in $tan^{-1}(t)$? Going one step further, aren't the solutions to this new system periodical? I have a proof that shows that the original system's solutions are not. I'm really confused, and would appreciate it a lot if you could elaborate more.

Comment: the derivative of $\arctan t$ is $1/(t^2+1)$   @Otomeram  and  $x'(u) $ means $\dfrac {dx}{du}$

Comment: You're correct, my bad. I still don't get how you can just replace $t$ for $u$ inside $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It's a change of variable so that the system becomes autonomous and easier to solve.... That's all @Otomeram

Comment: Yes, but if I recall correctly, the solutions to this system are circunferences that orbit periodically around the origin. The solutions to the original system are not periodic, so how can these systems be equivalent then?

Comment: In the line you just added expanding the chain rule, shouldn't all equalities be evaluated at $t$ if we are talking about function identity? Shouldn't $x$ and $y$ then be evaluated at $\tan u$ instead of $u$?

Comment: A function of $\tan u$ is also a function of the variable $u$ @Otomeram

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126974/discussion-between-otomeram-and-aryadeva).

Comment: This is just a common abuse of notation. $x(u)$ is a different function than $x(t)$. It would be better to at least use some kind of marker, $\tilde x(u)=x(\tan(u))$ for instance.

Comment: Thanks  @LutzLehmann  I corrected my answer.